# How do I write a two-word type in JSON:API?

Tags: json-api

I want to post an alien artifact to my server.

Do I write type="alienArtifact"

or type="alien-artifact"

or something completely different?

I looked here https://jsonapi.org/format/ but is only deals with simple types, "objects".

Comment: Is this question about JSON:API specification or just one random REST API that serves JSON responses? You added JSON:API tag but included a link to a different API design in your question.

Comment: I thought I clarified that in the header, the tag, but I see that the link might be confusing.
This is about the JSON:API specification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON:API specification is agnostic if you use `kebab-case`, `snake_case` or `camelCase` for field names but it comes with a [recommendation](https://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#naming):

> Member names SHOULD be camel-cased (i.e., wordWordWord)

This recommendation was change in October 2018. It was `kebab-case` before. Therefor many articles about JSON:API specification and documentation for libraries are still using `kebab-case`. These arguments were given as main reasons for this change:

> - camelCased names can be used directly as identifiers in almost all    programming languages, making json:api easier to get started with and to work with over time. Dasherized names are usable as identifiers pretty much only in Lisps.
> - camelCased names are the most common convention in the JS community,    and JS is the biggest user of JSON:API
> - camelCased names are slightly shorter than dasherized (or snake-case)    names, which could help with url character limits in
>     the case of    complex filters or other types of complex queries
>     (e.g., some GraphQL    like “deep querying” feature) that we might
>     serialize into urls in    the future.

You could find more details about this change in the [appropriate pull request](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/pull/1297).